# Merge DIV so that content properly fills another DIV

Tags: css, html

I have two DIV's that are stacking on top of each other. I would like the content from the `container` DIV to fill the bottom portion of the `box-2` DIV otherwise I am only able to get the bottom portion of the `box-2` DIV length to extend by using `<br>` and of course that does not work well as the results that are returned vary in length. Below, the DIV with the lighter border (DIV `box-2`) does not fill in respect to the contents of DIV `container`. How should the container be handled to ensure it fills the lower `box-2`? Should the `container` CSS be merged with `box-2`?

[image]

Here's an example based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16611274/666891 although it does not fill the `box-2` div.

[image]

Here is the respective HTML code, sorry for the lack of indention.

```
<div class="box-2">
<div class="border-top">
<div class="border-bot">
<div class="border-left">
<div class="border-right">
<div class="corner-top-left">
<div class="corner-top-right">
<div class="corner-bot-left">
<div class="corner-bot-right">
<div class="box-indent1">
<div id="boxtwo-header">
<div align="center">
<?php
echo "$myrow3[2]";
?>
</div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<?php
echo '<div class="container">';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name WHERE Field4 = '$cat'",$db);
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo '<div class="item"><p><a href="page.php?page=' . $res['Field2'] . '&' . $res['Field6'] . '">' . $res['Field1'] . '</a></p></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Here is the `box-2` CSS:

```
.box-2 {
        margin: 0 4px 39px 3px;
}
#boxtwo-header {
/*      background: url(images/titles-act3.gif) no-repeat 0% 0%; */
        position: absolute;
        color: #000;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 26px;
        width: 612px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        border-top-width: 0px;
        border-right-width: 0px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 0px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-right-style: solid;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #E9E9E9;
        border-right-color: #E9E9E9;
        border-bottom-color: #E9E9E9;
        border-left-color: #E9E9E9;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: -5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: -3px;
}

.box-2 .border-top {
        background: #fff url(images/border-top2.gif) repeat-x 0% 0%;
}
.box-2 .border-bot {
        background: url(images/border-bot2.gif) repeat-x 0% 100%;
}
.box-2 .border-left {
        background: url(images/border-left2.gif) repeat-y 0% 0%;
}
.box-2 .border-right {
        background: url(images/border-right2.gif) repeat-y 100% 0%;
}
.box-2 .corner-top-left {
        background: url(images/corner-top-left2.gif) no-repeat 0% 0%;
}
.box-2 .corner-top-right {
        background: url(images/corner-top-right2.gif) no-repeat 100% 0%;

.box-2 .corner-bot-left {
        background: url(images/corner-bot-left2.gif) no-repeat 0% 100%;
}
.box-2 .corner-bot-right {
        background: url(images/corner-bot-right2.gif) no-repeat 100% 100%;
        width: 100%;
}
.box-2 .box-indent {
        padding: 4px 33px 32px 37px;
}
.box-2 .box-indent1 {
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
}
.box-2 p {
        padding: 0 0 15px 0 !important;
        line-height: 1.417em !important;
        color: #000000 !important;
}
```

The `container` CSS which creates a two column layout for the output of the MySQL query:

```
.container {
        width: 600px;
        float: left;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-spacing: ;
        border-style: outset;
        border-collapse: collapse;
}
.container .item {
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        height: 30px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.container .item a{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10.5pt;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
}
.container .item a:hover {
        color: #FF0000;
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a two-column layout for a list of `.item` elements generated from you MySQL query.  Your items are listed left to right and then they wrap into multiple lines.

Comment: You are also trying to create a border with rounded corners.  Have you considered using `border-radius` from CSS3?

Comment: That's correct, the `container` DIV does create a two column layout. I'll add that to the question. Feel free to provide CSS3 code recommendations but the priority is to get the `container` DIV data to fall into the `box-2` one way or another.

Comment: and you say sql injection attack

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I did not write the MySQL queries but feel free to provide feedback on mitigating the vulnerability if you would like.

Comment: Off-topic but using `<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>` this way is a pretty bad practice.

Comment: I agree but I was doing it for demonstration purposes in order to expand the `box-2` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Simpler Approach

I am addressing the problem of getting a two-column layout to work.

See the demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6L4MK/

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <p><a href="#">Your label...1</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p><a href="#">Your label...2</a></p>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="item">
        <p><a href="#">Your label...7</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: auto; /* Important*/
    width: 600px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
}
.container .item {
    overflow: auto; /* Important */
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: auto; /* Let the .item p determine the box height ... */
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    outline: 1px dotted blue; /* Optional for demonstration... */
}
.container .item p {
    outline: 1px dashed blue; /* Optional for demonstration... */
    margin: 1.00em 0.50em; /* Gives you some control on the spacing...*/
}
```

**How This Works**

You have a parent container (`div.container`) with a fixed width of 600px, that contains child elements `div.item` which has a width of 300px.  Each `.item` contains a `<p>` with a `<a>`.

You want each `.item` to form rows of two, left to right, up to down.

You had the right idea, apply `float: left` to `div.item`.  The tricky bit is dealing with the floated elements that are not setting the height of `.container` and collapsing margins.

First: set `overflow: auto` to `.container`, that way your border will enclose all the floated elements. (Technically, this generates a "block formatting context".)

Second, for `.item`, set the `height: auto`, no need to fix it here.  If you do, you need to make sure that the height is sufficient for the height of the labels and any margins on the child elements.

Also, set `overflow: auto` on `.item` to make sure that you don't get into trouble with collapsing margins.

Finally, style the inner paragraphs/links by applying a margin to `.item p`.

Originally, the height of 30px on `.item` was not tall enough to accommodate both the text and the default margins on the `<p>` elements, which would cause margins to interact between the floats and break the two column layout, but this was not obvious since you did not have `overflow: auto` on `.container`.  This may sound obscure, but easy enough to deal with some experience.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation of the code you provided! I have updated the question with a screen-shot of the code you provided but I am getting similar results. The trick is that I am trying to place the content from the `container` div into the `box-2` div. Currently they kind of overlap.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with `.box-2` and demonstrated how to add the title/header and made some comments to guide you how to adjust spacing and so on.  You should be well on your way!

Answer (score 0):

a jsfiddle of your actual markup would help debug this.

It looks like the `.container` div is being floated, I can't see why this is needed, if you remove the float the content should push `.box-2` to the right height.

If you do need to float `.container` you can set `overflow:hidden` on `.box-2` which should clear any floats resulting in the box being the correct height.

Comment: If `float: left;` is removed from `container`, it still does not fill the `box-2` div.